# How can I set the Android SDK path manually?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

The SDK manager within Intellij IDEA 2018.1 seems to be broken on my systems (Arch Linux and Ubuntu 18.04). It downloads everything as expected and I get a working SDK and a working set of tools in the chosen directory, but when it's actually finished, it keeps loading and the "Finish" button stays greyed out. If I kill the process and start it again, it says "Nothing to do", but keeps loading anyways.

Maybe someone has a fix for that, which would be great, but it would also help, if I could manually set the SDK path somewhere (e.g. in some config files), so that I don't have to go through the broken download procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after installing 2018.1 on my Mac.  Mine was slightly different, in that I had reinstalled macOS fresh, and copied over my prior project files.  When I installed the OS, I inadvertently changed my home folder name.  When I opened IntelliJ for the first time, I opened a project and my Android SDK was pointing to my OLD home folder.  When I tried changing it, I got the locking up after install was done, like you did.  Force quit and try again gave me the "nothing to do".

I tried going into preferences without opening a project, and the SDK path was blank again.  After pointing it to the correct place, it installed everything again, and promptly locked up.

I looked all over, but couldn't find where this path is stored.  I ended up uninstalling 2018.1 and going back to 2017.3.3, which is what I had before reinstalling macOS.

Not the answer you were looking for, I'm sure, but I would recommend rolling back to a prior version.  Looks like 2018.1 is bugged.

Comment: Thanks for the information anyway. I still don't know, what caused the issue and I vaguely remember, that I also found a closed bug report somewhere, where nobody knew, what went wrong. Now it works sometimes and somtimes it doesn't. Life is strange.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on your app name on the project view, choose "Open module settings" in the drop down menu, click on "SDK Location" and change the SDK path to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done. But I hoped I could somehow get around the issue and have my SDK nicely managed by the IDE (using the global setting, not the project specific).

Comment: Then go to the "File" menu, click on the "settings" entry, open the "Appearance & behaviour" folder, open the "system settings" folder then click on "Android SDK". Now, click on the "Edit" link to change your SDK location.

Comment: Well, this is what didn't work, as I described in my question.